# Fragmented MP4: TrackFragHeader TFHD must have TrackID, is this in the spec?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I'm building a fragmented mp4 muxer and noticed that the track id is repeated inside the TFHD.
If the video does not have this undocumented track id, it will simply not play.

Here's an example of a muxer adding it:
https://github.com/edgeware/mp4ff/blob/bb9320744777dc97f18034c8aed45a9bcdbaa995/mp4/tfhd.go#L154

I was relying on the open spec provided by Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-sstr/513ea48c-9a57-4792-a32a-fb6202ce2a58

Is this an addition to the spec? Is the spec provided by Microsoft wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mandatory. How else will the reader know which track does the fragment belong to?

As per ISO 14496 Part 12 (2015):

```
aligned(8) class TrackFragmentHeaderBox  
 extends FullBox(‘tfhd’, 0, tf_flags){ 
 unsigned int(32) track_ID; 
 // all the following are optional fields 
 unsigned int(64) base_data_offset; 
 unsigned int(32) sample_description_index; 
 unsigned int(32) default_sample_duration; 
 unsigned int(32) default_sample_size; 
 unsigned int(32) default_sample_flags 
}
```